# Ordering a list of WordPress users by array value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sql-order-by

Imagine we had a list of users and we were trying to match YOU to one of them. You have a list of 10 things and you have to select the ones you like.

Say: chocolate, sailing, running, biking, NetFlix, etc...

Depending on which checkbox you check, it stores it as an array, or a string, in the database (I am flexible over either).

So I need now to order the list of users by who has ticked the most check boxes similar to you.

Simply put, if I select "chocolate, sailing & running" and someone just had "chocolate" then they would be further down the list than someone who had the exact same 3 I had picked.

In trying to hack the WP_User_Query using the `pre_user_query` action hook, I have the following line:

```
$query->query_orderby = 'ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET("chocolate", wp_usermeta.meta_value) > 0 ASC';
```

...but with no luck.

I have one user `meta_key` called `babud_likes` and the array is stored in the meta_value for that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could store the data as a binary string? For example, if we have the categories Chocolate, Sweets, Candy, Football we would represent each of these as a single bit in a known position in a string. For example, for someone who likes Chocolate, Candy and Football we could write, using the structure (Chocolate,Sweets,Candy,Football):

```
1011
```

or for someone who likes Chocolate, Sweets and Football we could write

```
1101
```

Say we write a simple SQL query (`SELECT id, likes FROM users WHERE id=1 OR id=2`). We could then get the two `likes` values and do a bitwise AND, which compares each bit in the string, and returns a 1 if both bits match. So for our two sample users, we would do;

```
$result = 1011 & 1101;
// Outputs '1001'
```

From the result we can infer that both people like Chocolate and Football due to the fact that there is a 1 in the first position indicating Chocolate, and a 1 in the 4th position indicating Football.

In terms of intergrating this into Wordpress I would consider [creating an all new table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) for the users - You will run into problems doing this with just the default Wordpress user table eventually.